# pytest: I can run all tests from the root folder but I can't run tests individually (ImportError)

Tags: python, pytest

I can run all tests with pytest with no issues if I run from the test “root” directory, but if I try to run an individual test, I get an `ImportError`.

I have the following directory structure:

```
pytestExample/
    conftest.py
    src/
        conftest.py
        classA.py
        config.py
    tests/
        test_classA.py
```

Here is what each file contains:

**conftest.py, src/conftest.py**:

*Both instances of conftest.py are empty files. I found that I had to place `conftest.py` in the code root directory (`pytestExample/`) and the `src/` directory for pytest to find the tests in test_classA.py.*

**tests/test_classA.py**:

```
import unittest
from src.classA import ClassA
import src.config
import pytest

class ClassATest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.classA = ClassA()

    def test_checkVarAValue(self):
        self.assertEqual(12345, self.classA.getVarA())
    
    def test_setAndCheckVarA(self):
        self.classA.setVarA(9876)
        self.assertEqual(9876, self.classA.getVarA())
```

**src/classA.py**:

```
import config

class ClassA:
    varA = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.varA = config.DEFAULT_VAR_A
    
    def getVarA(self):
        return self.varA
    
    def setVarA(self, value):
        self.varA = value
```

**src/config.py**:

```
DEFAULT_VAR_A = 12345
```

---

If I run pytest from `pyTestExample\`, all tests run fine and pass:
[Running from code root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG5gt.png)

However, if I try to run a test individually, I get an ImportError:
[Running a test individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8Oc.png)

I also see the same error if I just try to run the test directory:
[Running test directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubq5n.png)

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: Might be an instance of [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2564). Have you tried running `pytest` directly instead of `python -m pytest`?

Comment: Thanks - that pointed me in the right direction.